# Copy Excel formulas from one workbook to another using VBA and maintaining the names that already exist

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code to copy formulas from one workbook to another.

```
    For Each r In templateWbk.Sheets("BSC").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        addressRange = r.Address
        r.Copy instanceWbk.Sheets("BSC").Range(addressRange)
    Next
```

Occationally I get a popup that says "The name "xxxxx" already exists. Click Yes to use that version of the name, or click No to rename the version of "xxxxx" you're moving or copying.

I don't want this popup to appear. I always want the exact content of the cells to be copied and nothing more, in other words I want to use the existing version of the name. This is the major thing I need help with.

The code is also rather slow as the sheets have many formulas. So if you can suggest a faster approach I would be thankful for that as well.

Comment: [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837103/reference-data-in-closed-excel-sheet/17838174#17838174)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you simply set the value in one workbook to equal the value in the other? This would keep eliminate the "copy" method:

```
For Each r In templateWbk.Sheets("BSC").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    instanceWbk.Sheets("BSC").Range(r.Address).Formula _
    = templateWbk.Sheets("BSC").Range(r.Address).Formula
Next
```

Also, you may try to change the DisplayAlerts property:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Untested for your scenario, but a good way to get rid of many popups.

Comment: That looks like it could work, I'm testing it currently. Why do you have templateWbk.Sheets("BSC").Cells.Range(r.Address).Formula rather than templateWbk.Sheets("BSC").Range(r.Address).Formula?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to take it out. What you have suggested would be correct, I've edited.